# Not able to take a thread dump using Jstack.

Tags: jstack

I want to take a thread dump of my java - Jmeter machine. In my Jmeter machine I can see many of the threads are not closed and stucked after test timings. To debug more I tried to take thread dump(using "jstack -PID>>Fileae.txt" command).  but this command is still running after 24Hrs, although this has created a empty textfile.
Why I am not able to take a thread dump of that java process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

‘jstack’ is an effective command line tool to capture thread dumps. jstack tool is shipped in JDK_HOMEbin folder. Here is the command that you need to issue to capture thread dump:

jstack -l   >

where

pid: is the Process Id of the application, whose thread dump should be captured

file-path: is the file path where thread dump will be written in to.
Example:

jstack -l 37320 > /opt/tmp/threadDump.txt
As per the example thread dump of the process would be generated in /opt/tmp/threadDump.txt file.

Jstack tool is included in JDK since Java 5. If you are running in older version of java, consider using other options.